# How to add, move and delete multiple images NOT pulled from ImagePicker and have them viewed on a separate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, image

I'm new to xCode and I have three items all related to each other that I'm trying to get a solution for.

1. I have found ways to choose an image from the photo library and how to get that image to show up on the view controller and i know how to add an image with an Image View...however I'm having a hard time figuring out if i can have a stacked view of images/buttons that i provide the user to choose from that would show up in a separate view controller once the image/button is pushed. I'm having a hard time figuring out the code to  add that image to the view controller as i don't really want to add a View Image box to the view controller as that would limit the # of images that could go in the view controller and I'd like them to keep adding the image as often as they choose.
2. The images then need to be animated and move wherever the user chooses. I think there's enough on this topic that I can pick this up for inclusion in my app, but if you feel like being extra helpful and you can easily provide a suggestion here that would sure help me out :). I'm also including this here so it helps make sense with the third item.
3. Lastly, the user would need the option to delete the image (preferably by dragging the image off from the top of the page, but I'm open to other methods to delete the image.)

Any thoughts on any one of these items is appreciated!

Comment: Could you add some drawings or wireframes so we can understand exactly what you want to achieve ? I don't really understand your first point

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - Below, the view controller is the one i want to put the images into, and on right are picture button place holders for images that will be added later that will all be different. I want to be able to click on one of the images on the right and have it place the image into the view controller on the left, and for the user to be able to do that as many times as they want with whatever mix of the different photos as they choose. Let me know if that still doesn't make sense.  /Users/jenilenkersdorfer/Desktop/Xcode example.png

Comment: I took a screen shot of the storyboard that I'm currently working on, but I'm not sure how to add it here...could you tell me how to do so or I could email it?

Comment: On Udemy, there's a free course from The App Dojo that is called "This is How You Make iPhone Apps - iOS Development Course" and in Lesson 8 he gives an example of building an app that randomly places photos on a view controller that are from the photo library - I want to do something similar, but want the option for the user to choose images to be from a table of images that I provide in the app rather than from the photo library, and I'd prefer to delete the photos with a drag off the top of the page.